# Play audio with php function

Tags: php, audio

Hello I have a php function so:

```
function set_timer($data)
{
    $t = strtotime($data["staff_note"]);
    $now = strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));

    if ($t < $now)
            $left = 0;

    else
            $left = $t - $now;

    return "<div class='timer-quick' data-seconds-left='$left'></div>";
}
```

Then I need to play audio file in True condition, when $left=0.

Thanks by your help

Comment: 1. since function is returning someting so playing sound  is not possible inside function. 2, you need some Html5 audio/third-party  to play sound  like:- http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/

Comment: Play audio on the server?

Comment: No in client by calling JS library could be!